# Cannot find module 'express-stormpath' when starting server

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, express, stormpath

When I try to run `node server.js` (in normal terminal without being a superuser or root) I get this error:

```
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~/my-webapp$ node server.js
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express-stormpath'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alphaunlimitedg/my-webapp/server.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~/my-webapp$
```

I've installed the express package in root, superuser and normaluser with the command: `npm install express`

And it worked, didn't give any errors! But it still displays the error above. Any ideas how I can resolve this?

PS: this was the procedure I've followed shown below:

```
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ npm install express
/home/alphaunlimitedg
└─┬ express@4.14.0 
  ├─┬ accepts@1.3.3 
  │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.11 
  │ │ └── mime-db@1.23.0 
  │ └── negotiator@0.6.1 
  ├── array-flatten@1.1.1 
  ├── content-disposition@0.5.1 
  ├── content-type@1.0.2 
  ├── cookie@0.3.1 
  ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6 
  ├─┬ debug@2.2.0 
  │ └── ms@0.7.1 
  ├── depd@1.1.0 
  ├── encodeurl@1.0.1 
  ├── escape-html@1.0.3 
  ├── etag@1.7.0 
  ├─┬ finalhandler@0.5.0 
  │ ├── statuses@1.3.0 
  │ └── unpipe@1.0.0 
  ├── fresh@0.3.0 
  ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1 
  ├── methods@1.1.2 
  ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0 
  │ └── ee-first@1.1.1 
  ├── parseurl@1.3.1 
  ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7 
  ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.1.2 
  │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0 
  │ └── ipaddr.js@1.1.1 
  ├── qs@6.2.0 
  ├── range-parser@1.2.0 
  ├─┬ send@0.14.1 
  │ ├── destroy@1.0.4 
  │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.5.0 
  │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1 
  │ │ └── setprototypeof@1.0.1 
  │ └── mime@1.3.4 
  ├── serve-static@1.11.1 
  ├─┬ type-is@1.6.13 
  │ └── media-typer@0.3.0 
  ├── utils-merge@1.0.0 
  └── vary@1.1.0 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/alphaunlimitedg/package.json'
npm WARN alphaunlimitedg No description
npm WARN alphaunlimitedg No repository field.
npm WARN alphaunlimitedg No README data
npm WARN alphaunlimitedg No license field.
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ express --help
The program 'express' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install node-express-generator
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ sudo apt install node-express-generator
[sudo] password for alphaunlimitedg: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp javascript-common libjs-inherits libjs-jquery libjs-node-uuid
  libjs-underscore libssl-dev libssl-doc libuv1 libuv1-dev zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  node-accepts node-buffer-crc32 node-commander node-cookie
  node-cookie-signature node-crc node-debug node-depd node-escape-html
  node-etag node-express node-fresh node-media-typer node-merge-descriptors
  node-methods node-mime node-mime-types node-mkdirp node-negotiator
  node-on-finished node-parseurl node-path-to-regexp node-qs node-range-parser
  node-send node-serve-static node-type-is node-utils-merge
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  node-accepts node-buffer-crc32 node-commander node-cookie
  node-cookie-signature node-crc node-debug node-depd node-escape-html
  node-etag node-express node-express-generator node-fresh node-media-typer
  node-merge-descriptors node-methods node-mime node-mime-types node-mkdirp
  node-negotiator node-on-finished node-parseurl node-path-to-regexp node-qs
  node-range-parser node-send node-serve-static node-type-is node-utils-merge
0 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 203 kB/227 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1999 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-negotiator all 0.4.8-1 [6980 B]
Get:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-mime-types all 2.0.2-2 [17,4 kB]
Get:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-accepts all 1.1.1-1 [5314 B]
Get:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-buffer-crc32 all 0.2.1-1 [4876 B]
Get:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-commander all 2.4.0-1 [13,2 kB]
Get:6 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-cookie all 0.1.2-2 [3692 B]
Get:7 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-cookie-signature all 1.0.3-1 [3320 B]
Get:8 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-crc all 3.0.0-3 [8378 B]
Get:9 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-debug all 2.1.0+dfsg-2 [12,3 kB]
Get:10 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-depd all 1.0.0-1 [9982 B]
Get:11 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-escape-html all 1.0.1-1 [3016 B]
Get:12 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-etag all 1.4.0-1 [4692 B]
Get:13 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-parseurl all 1.3.0-1 [4544 B]
Get:14 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-methods all 1.1.0-1 [3104 B]
Get:15 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-media-typer all 0.3.0-1 [5408 B]
Get:16 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-type-is all 1.5.2-1 [5502 B]
Get:17 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-fresh all 0.2.0-1 [3226 B]
Get:18 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-on-finished all 2.1.0-2 [5668 B]
Get:19 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-range-parser all 0.0.4+git7d1cd72a-1 [3286 B]
Get:20 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-send all 0.9.4-1 [10,8 kB]
Get:21 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-merge-descriptors all 0.0.2-1 [3226 B]
Get:22 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-path-to-regexp all 1.0.1-1 [6512 B]
Get:23 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-utils-merge all 1.0.0-1 [3362 B]
Get:24 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-serve-static all 1.6.4-2 [6160 B]
Get:25 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-express all 4.1.1~dfsg-1 [41,5 kB]
Get:26 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 node-express-generator all 4.0.0-2 [7478 B]
Fetched 203 kB in 0s (558 kB/s)                  
Selecting previously unselected package node-negotiator.
(Reading database ... 215457 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../node-negotiator_0.4.8-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-negotiator (0.4.8-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-mime-types.
Preparing to unpack .../node-mime-types_2.0.2-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-mime-types (2.0.2-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-accepts.
Preparing to unpack .../node-accepts_1.1.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-accepts (1.1.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-buffer-crc32.
Preparing to unpack .../node-buffer-crc32_0.2.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-buffer-crc32 (0.2.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-commander.
Preparing to unpack .../node-commander_2.4.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-commander (2.4.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-cookie.
Preparing to unpack .../node-cookie_0.1.2-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-cookie (0.1.2-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-cookie-signature.
Preparing to unpack .../node-cookie-signature_1.0.3-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-cookie-signature (1.0.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-crc.
Preparing to unpack .../node-crc_3.0.0-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-crc (3.0.0-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-debug.
Preparing to unpack .../node-debug_2.1.0+dfsg-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-debug (2.1.0+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-depd.
Preparing to unpack .../node-depd_1.0.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-depd (1.0.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-escape-html.
Preparing to unpack .../node-escape-html_1.0.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-escape-html (1.0.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-etag.
Preparing to unpack .../node-etag_1.4.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-etag (1.4.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-parseurl.
Preparing to unpack .../node-parseurl_1.3.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-parseurl (1.3.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-qs.
Preparing to unpack .../node-qs_2.2.4-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-qs (2.2.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-methods.
Preparing to unpack .../node-methods_1.1.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-methods (1.1.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-media-typer.
Preparing to unpack .../node-media-typer_0.3.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-media-typer (0.3.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-type-is.
Preparing to unpack .../node-type-is_1.5.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-type-is (1.5.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-fresh.
Preparing to unpack .../node-fresh_0.2.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-fresh (0.2.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-mime.
Preparing to unpack .../node-mime_1.3.4-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-mime (1.3.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-on-finished.
Preparing to unpack .../node-on-finished_2.1.0-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-on-finished (2.1.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-range-parser.
Preparing to unpack .../node-range-parser_0.0.4+git7d1cd72a-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-range-parser (0.0.4+git7d1cd72a-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-send.
Preparing to unpack .../node-send_0.9.4-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-send (0.9.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-merge-descriptors.
Preparing to unpack .../node-merge-descriptors_0.0.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-merge-descriptors (0.0.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-path-to-regexp.
Preparing to unpack .../node-path-to-regexp_1.0.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-path-to-regexp (1.0.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-utils-merge.
Preparing to unpack .../node-utils-merge_1.0.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-utils-merge (1.0.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-serve-static.
Preparing to unpack .../node-serve-static_1.6.4-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-serve-static (1.6.4-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-express.
Preparing to unpack .../node-express_4.1.1~dfsg-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-express (4.1.1~dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-mkdirp.
Preparing to unpack .../node-mkdirp_0.5.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-mkdirp (0.5.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package node-express-generator.
Preparing to unpack .../node-express-generator_4.0.0-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking node-express-generator (4.0.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up node-negotiator (0.4.8-1) ...
Setting up node-mime-types (2.0.2-2) ...
Setting up node-accepts (1.1.1-1) ...
Setting up node-buffer-crc32 (0.2.1-1) ...
Setting up node-commander (2.4.0-1) ...
Setting up node-cookie (0.1.2-2) ...
Setting up node-cookie-signature (1.0.3-1) ...
Setting up node-crc (3.0.0-3) ...
Setting up node-debug (2.1.0+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up node-depd (1.0.0-1) ...
Setting up node-escape-html (1.0.1-1) ...
Setting up node-etag (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up node-parseurl (1.3.0-1) ...
Setting up node-qs (2.2.4-1) ...
Setting up node-methods (1.1.0-1) ...
Setting up node-media-typer (0.3.0-1) ...
Setting up node-type-is (1.5.2-1) ...
Setting up node-fresh (0.2.0-1) ...
Setting up node-mime (1.3.4-1) ...
Setting up node-on-finished (2.1.0-2) ...
Setting up node-range-parser (0.0.4+git7d1cd72a-1) ...
Setting up node-send (0.9.4-1) ...
Setting up node-merge-descriptors (0.0.2-1) ...
Setting up node-path-to-regexp (1.0.1-1) ...
Setting up node-utils-merge (1.0.0-1) ...
Setting up node-serve-static (1.6.4-2) ...
Setting up node-express (4.1.1~dfsg-1) ...
Setting up node-mkdirp (0.5.0-1) ...
Setting up node-express-generator (4.0.0-2) ...
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~$ cd my-webapp
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~/my-webapp$ node server.js
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express-stormpath'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alphaunlimitedg/my-webapp/server.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~/my-webapp$ sudo apt-get install node-express
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
node-express is already the newest version (4.1.1~dfsg-1).
node-express set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp javascript-common libjs-inherits libjs-jquery libjs-node-uuid
  libjs-underscore libssl-dev libssl-doc libuv1 libuv1-dev zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~/my-webapp$ node server.js
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express-stormpath'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alphaunlimitedg/my-webapp/server.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
alphaunlimitedg@AUNs-PC:~/my-webapp$
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) The error is quite self-explanatory : `Cannot find module 'express-stormpath'`

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your `server.js` file contains the statement `require('express-stormpath');` but that the module isn't located in your `/<project>/node_modules` folder.

You can fix this by doing `npm i --save express-stormpath` in your project directory.

Comment: lol I'm just a new starter/novice with Linux programming so I really appreciate ur help guys, its sometimes hard to get a specific answer but this helped me a lot thanks again :)

Comment: I'll test this out asap